# Cant understand what following code does in R

Tags: r

While checking the query of NLP, I got this code. Can anyone describe what it does:

```
 candidates <- reactive({
    if (is.null(ng)) { return(NULL) }
    pred.time <- system.time({
      candidates <- predictN(input$inputtext, ng(), ngramRange = 1:4)            
    })
    values$pred.time <- HTML(sprintf("%3.2f s", pred.time[3]))
    candidates
  })
```

Comment: For starters, it appears to be part of a shiny app, so you'll at least need to understand what the `input`s and `value`s refer to.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll `inputtext` is clearly user input text and `values` is a standard container in Shiny which, in this case, is going to hold the prediction time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a [reactive](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/) (live updating) function that either returns NULL if `ng` is NULL, or otherwise times how long it takes to run a prediction based on some user-input text value using `ng`.

`ng` is apparently a statistical model based on n-gram text mining with 1-grams to 4-grams.

It also outputs the time that it records as HTML formatted text.